# Reading file with fread() in reverse order causes memory leak?

Tags: c++, c, io, low-level

I have a program that basically does this:

1. Opens some binary file
2. Reads the file **backwards** (by backwards, I mean it starts near EOF, and ends reading at beginning of file, i.e. reads the file "right-to-left"), using 4MB chunks
3. Closes the file

My question is: why memory consumption looks like below, even though there are no obvious memory leaks in my attached code?

[image: Memory consumption during program execution]

Here's the source of program that was run to obtain above image:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    //allocate stuff
    const int bufferSize = 4*1024*1024;
    FILE *fileHandle = fopen("./input.txt", "rb");
    if (!fileHandle)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No file for you\n");
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[bufferSize];
    if (!buffer)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No buffer for you\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //get file size. file can be BIG, hence the fseeko() and ftello()
    //instead of fseek() and ftell().
    fseeko(fileHandle, 0, SEEK_END);
    off_t totalSize = ftello(fileHandle);
    fseeko(fileHandle, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //read the file... in reverse order. This is important.
    for (off_t pos = totalSize - bufferSize, j = 0;
        pos >= 0;
        pos -= bufferSize, j ++)
    {
        if (j % 10 == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,
                "reading like crazy: %lld / %lld\n",
                pos, totalSize);
        }

        /*
         * below is the heart of the problem. see notes below
         */
        //seek to desired position
        fseeko(fileHandle, pos, SEEK_SET);
        //read the chunk
        fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), bufferSize, fileHandle);
    }

    fclose(fileHandle);
    delete []buffer;
}
```

I have also following observations:

1. **Even though RAM usage jumps by 1GB, the whole program uses only 5MB thorough whole execution.**
2. Commenting call to `fread()` out **makes memory leak go away**. This is weird, since I don't allocate anything anywhere near it, that could trigger memory leak...
3. Also, reading the file normally instead of backwards (= commenting call to `fseeko()` out), **makes memory leak go away as well**. This is the *ultra-weird part*.

Further information...

1. Following doesn't help:

   1. Checking results of `fread()` - yields nothing out of ordinary.
   2. Switching to normal, 32-bit `fseek` and `ftell`.
   3. Doing stuff like `setbuf(fileHandle, NULL)`.
   4. Doing stuff like `setvbuf(fileHandle, NULL, _IONBF, *any integer*)`.
2. Compiled with g++ 4.5.3 on Windows 7 via cygwin and mingw; without any optimalizations, just `g++ test.cpp -o test`. Both present such behaviour.
3. The file used in tests was 4GB long, full of zeros.
4. The weird pause in the middle of the chart could be explained with some kind of temporary I/O hangup, unrelated to this question.
5. Finally, if I wrap reading in infinite loop... the memory usage stops increasing after first iteration.

---

I think it has to do with some kind of internal cache building up till it's filled with whole file. How does it really work behind the scenes? How can I prevent that in a portable way??

Comment: have you tried running it through valgrind? (or any other memory debuggers)

Comment: Firstly, this is not good `const int bufferSize = 4*1024*1024`... it should be `const int bufferSize = sizeof( int )*1024*1024`.

Comment: @JacobPollack: The 4*1024*1024 part is just 4MB. It could be anything, for example 8KB. It has nothing to do with size of integer...

Comment: @Jocke: Using memory debuggers is probably going be useless - thing is that in any resource monitor I use, the whole program uses 5MB.

Comment: Regarding the memory buffer you use, I would advise using `std::vector<unsigned char>` to avoid having to call `new[]` and `delete[]` manually. Of course, probably nothing to do with your leak... Regarding memory debuggers, valgrind has a mode call `massif` which allows you to identify *where* memory is allocated on top of giving a profile of how much memory is consumed at a given instant. Knowing where the leak comes from is half the solution in most cases.

Comment: I don't see a memory leak. I see a huge memory usage during the execution of your program, but that's not at all the same thing as a memory leak.

Comment: I agree with @TomTanner.  There is no leak, and your point #5 proves it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, this is more an OS issue (or even an OS resource use reporting issue) than an issue with your program. Of course, it only uses 5 MB of memory: 1 MB for itself (libs, stack etc.) and 4 MB for the buffer. Whenever you do a fread(), the OS seems to "bind" part of the file to your process, and seems to release it not at the same speed. As memory use on your machine is low, this is not a problem: The OS just keeps the already read data "hanging around" longer than necessary, probably assuming, that your application might read it again, soon, and then it doesn't have to do that binding again.

If memory pressure was higher, than the OS is very likely to unbind the memory faster, so that jump on your memory usage history would be smaller.

Comment: In my opinion, reading file backwards is a simple task. Why does the OS (Windows 7) iteratively cache the whole 4GB file, till it runs out of memory and it has to resort to page file, then...? (It does it, depending on my buffer size...)

Comment: Are you sure, that Win7 is busy paging? Or is it just busy re-reading your 4 Gig file, which it (partly) threw out of its file cache because of clumsiness? Because you are reading backwards, the disk activity from reading the file sounds likely very similiar to that of intense paging.

Comment: The disk activity alone wouldn't pollute the RAM, would it? Confirmed same behavior on Win8.

Comment: Who says, that "RAM gets polluted"? Just because the OS locks a page (and thus reports it as "used"), doesn't mean, that it is dirty.

Comment: My whole system freezes when I read something using 4MB buffer. It's crazy. I don't want it. I don't need any kind of cache. How can I tell it to my OS, most preferably in portable way...?

Comment: @rr- Since your buffer size is constant, why are you allocating it dynamically?  Just declare `buffer` as a `static` array.

Comment: So what is the solution to this problem? Why it is happening is clear from the discussion. Can anything be done to release the memory held by fread() ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, although in Java but it doesn't matter in this context. I solved it by reading much bigger chunks at a time. I also read 4Mb size chunks, but when I increased it to 100-200 Mb the problem went away. Perhaps it'll do that for you as well. I'm on Windows 7.